# Combine custom run command and macro in Notepad++ 6.8

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, script, notepad++

Following very [useful guidance](http://huebler.blogspot.co.uk/2008/04/stata.html) by Friedrich Huebler on integrating [Stata](http://www.stata.com/) with Notepad++ I've added a set of run commands that are assigned to:

- <kbd>F9</kbd> - run selected line
- <kbd>F10</kbd> - run the whole file

I in addittion I have also created a macro that selects the current line, which is assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I usually run the commands in the following variants:

1. **Running Current Line**

   1.1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to select the current line.

   1.2. Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to send the current line to Stata
2. **Running Current File**

   2.1 Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to save file

   2.2 Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to send the whole file to Stata

Ideally, I would like to streamline that process. The ideal outcome would correspond to the following result:

- Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> selects whole line and sends it to Stata
- Key <kbd>F10</kbd> saves the current file and sends it to Stata

Ideally I would like to edit the existing macro files so I can the Stata run commands to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select and run the current line:

1. Install NppExec in Notepad++ Menu: Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager -> Find NppExec and install.
2. Put the following code into NppExec's console: Plugins -> NppExec -> Execute...

   ```
   SCI_SENDMSG 2453
   SCI_SENDMSG 2452
   "C:\ado\rundolines.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
   ```

   And of course please change `C:\ado\rundolines.exe` to your path of `rundolines.exe`. Save it to a new script and give it a name.
3. Put this new script into Notepad++'s menu: Plugins -> NppExec -> Advanced Options... -> Menu Item: choose your new script in "Associated script" and give it a name.
4. Give this new menu item a shortcut via Settings -> Shortcut Mapper...

For save and send the whole file:

Create a new script in NppExec using the command `npp_save`:

```
npp_save
"C:\ado\rundo.exe" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

After creating a new menu item and shortcut binding, you are done.